# Hilbert transform and Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

Assume the following relationship between the Hilbert and Fourier transforms:
$$
\mathcal{H}(f) = {\mathcal{F}^{-1}}(-i ~ \text{sgn}(\cdot) \cdot \mathcal{F}(f)),
$$

where $ \displaystyle [\mathcal{H}(f)](x) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \text{p.v.} \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{x - t} ~ d{x} $.

What happens when $ f(x)$ is a *distribution*? We know that the Fourier transform exists for distributions, but what about the Hilbert transform?

For example, take $ f(x) = x^{n} $. Its Fourier transform exists as the $ n $-th derivative of the delta function $ \delta(x) $. However, the integral
$$
\text{p.v.} \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{x - t} ~ d{x}
$$
is divergent. :(

Comment: You have taken the Fourier transform of $x^n$ as a distribution, but why do you treat the Hilbert transform of $x^n$ as a function[thus it is divergent]?

Comment: is $isgn$ actually $sign$?

Comment: What is ‘$ w $’, by the way?

Comment: @rschwieb $i$ is correct: see, e.g., [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Relationship_with_the_Fourier_transform).

Comment: @5pm  Oh :) I thought it might be a simple transposition. Good thing I didn't change it!

Answer (score 3):

The Hilbert transform is [anti-self-adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Anti-self_adjointness). Therefore, it is natural to define it on distribution by passing $\mathcal H$ to the test functions, similar to "pass the hat" definition of the Fourier transform. In fact, the Wikipedia article already [says this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Hilbert_transform_of_distributions).

Since the stated relation between $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal H$ holds for test functions, the duality-based definition implies that it holds for distributions as well.

Comment: This is not correct, since the Hilbert transform does not stabilize the Schwartz space (not test functions). That is, there is no "definition by dualizing", unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

The multiplication by "sign" (with or without a constant "$i$" in front) does not map Schwartz functions to Schwartz functions, so that the otherwise-appealing notion of defining an automorphism on (tempered?) distributions by defining it on (Schwartz?) test functions does not succeed here.

Although in general it is ... very risky... to *try* to "multiply" distributions, a more delicate approach does allow multiplication when the "singular sets" are disjoint.

In the case at hand, multiplication of a distribution by "sign" would make sense, for example, if the singular support does not contain $0$. Thus, a tempered distribution whose Fourier transform has singular support not including $0$ has a Hilbert transform.